# path not working on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a folder were i drop all my emoji pictures. now what i noticed is, the emojis dont show until i use setinterval to load the function that gets this image. so lets say i set the interval to 5 seconds. the page will load but the emojis will still be in unicode until the next 5 seconds when the interval i set hits and the function is being run. what i want is for it to run on load but its not working. dont know what else to do

```
$(function(){

$('.emojione').Emoji({
        path:'plugins/lib/img/'
});
});
```

Comment: try this
path:'/plugins/lib/img/'

Comment: just tried didnt work